# Ninja Form - Form and Field ID append _1 in the frontend

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

For one of the projects, we are using Ninja forms extensively. We are facing a unique issue.

The Form Id and Field Id are appending _1 in the frontend. When we look at the backend and the DB, the form id and field id are generated by Ninja forms without _1 appended to it.

So for example, the form id is 28. In the front end on page inspect it shows as nf-form-28_1.

A field id is 384, it shows as nf-form-384_1.

Please note that this is not happening with all forms or fields. Seem to be random behaviour which I am not able to figure out.

thanks

[Front end view of NF Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AREcZ.png)

[Front end view of Form ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KvjF.png)

[Db entry of the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsoOb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but thought I'd post this anyway in case it helps someone else.

This issue occurred for me recently when I had a plugin conflict with the All in one SEO plugin, and the form was actually being generated twice on the front end.
I discovered the plugin was the cause of the issue through a trial and error disabling of plugins one by one.

To resolve the issue I added in a filter to disable aioseo from parsing shortcodes:

add_filter( 'aioseo_disable_shortcode_parsing', '__return_true' );

Hope that helps someone else.